# Defining Entity Framework Core 6.0 constraints from model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using entity framework core to create a project's database using migrations.
My question is: Is there any way to pre-set constraints in the model's definition?

For example:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace net_ref.Models
{
    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }  

        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        public int PlayerPositionId { get; set; }

        public Team? Team { get; set; }

        public PlayerPosition? PlayerPosition { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I use that model and generate its migrations I get something like:

```
table.ForeignKey(onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade)
```

Is there a way I could do something like

```
[ForeignKey.Constraing.OnDelete.NoAction]
public int PlayerPositionId { get; set; }
```

to get something like

```
table.ForeignKey(onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction)
```

in the migrations once I run the --dotnet ef migrations add-- command?

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need/ want to use the Fluent API to define your constraint. And as an aside, please copy and paste your code as [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) markdown instead of as an image. [Why?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Please learn about how to create and configure an EF model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: I actually used Fluent API to change the constraints once the migrations were created, but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid changing the migrations once they're generated.

I'll have in mind what you told me about the code in images for future questions (this was my first question and didn't really know about it). Thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: You ought to not be changing the migrations unless really necessary. You'll need to remove that migration and re-add it again.
Rather change the configurations via the Fluent API. Then via Fluent API when you're defining your relationships, as the last method call `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);`